# Passing object from server from parent component to child component angular2

Tags: angular

I have two components 'ItemComponent' and 'ItemForm' and i need to pass an object retrieved from a http call from the 'ItemComponent' to the 'ItemForm'.

The ItemComponent

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'item',
    templateUrl: 'templates/item.html',
    directives: [ItemForm]
})

export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

    private routeParams: RouteParams;

    item: Item;

    title: String;

    constructor(
        private _service: ItemService,
        routeParams: RouteParams) {
        this.routeParams = routeParams;
    }

    fetch() {
        this._service.get(this.routeParams.get('id')).subscribe(item => {
                this.item = item
            },
            error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        if(this.routeParams.get('id')) {
            this.title = "Update Item";
            this.fetch();
        }
        else {
            this.title = "Add Item"
        }
    }
}
```

and the ItemForm

```ts
 @Component({
        selector: 'item-form',
        templateUrl: `<form #itemForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(itemForm)">
<input type="text [(ngModel)]="item.title">
</form>`
    })

    export class ItemFormComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() item: Item;

        private mode: String;
        private service: ItemService;

        constructor(service: ItemService, routeParams: RouteParams) {
            this.service = service;
            this.routeParams = routeParams;

            if(this.routeParams.get('id')) {
                this.mode = "edit";
            }
            else {
                this.mode = "create";
            }
        }

        onSubmit($form) {
            console.info("Mode", this.mode);

            if ($form.form.valid) {
            }
        }

        ngOnInit() {
           console.log(this.item);
        }
    }
```

The item object in the ItemFormComponent is undefined, despite passing it to the component

```ts
<item-form [item]='item'></item-form>
```

I know am doing something wrong, i dont just know what.

Comment: You're using a service... why do you want to use an Input()? You're doing twice the work.

Comment: @EricMartinez so i dont have to make an ajax call in the ItemForm component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start fetching in `ngOnInit()` of the `ItemComponent` and check in `ngOnInit()` of the `ItemFormComponent`. There is no guarantee (actually it's quite unlikely the response from the server already returned when `ngOnInit()` is run.

You can implement [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) in `ItemFormComponent` to get notified when the value arrives.

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'item-form',
    template: `<form #itemForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(itemForm)">
      <input type="text [(ngModel)]="item.title">
      </form>`
})
export class ItemFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() item: Item;

    private mode: String;
    private service: ItemService;

    constructor(service: ItemService, routeParams: RouteParams) {
        this.service = service;
        this.routeParams = routeParams;

        if(this.routeParams.get('id')) {
            this.mode = "edit";
        }
        else {
            this.mode = "create";
        }
    }

    onSubmit($form) {
        console.info("Mode", this.mode);

        if ($form.form.valid) {
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       console.log(this.item);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        if(changes['item'].currentValue) {
          console.log('ngOnChanges - changes = ' + changes['item'].currentValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The item object is still undefined in the ngOnChnages method. i checked using changes['item'].currentValue

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work. Did you check that `this.item = item` actually assigns a value? Can you try add `console.debug(this.item)` after the above line?

Comment: Mark fixed another issue `template` instead of `templateUrl`. Thanks @MarkRajcok !